MutableStateFlow not being updated on @Composable
Currently I have a WebAppInterface that detects the events of the web, such WebAppInterface is called inside a @Composable WebView, inside the WebAppInterface I have a function that I have successfully checked that detects the events of the Web and also updates within the class the variable eventNumber which is a StateFlow<Int>, but from within the @Composoable when I try to react to the changes of the value from this variable nothing happens. Here my code:
    class WebAppInterface {
    
        private var _eventNumber: MutableStateFlow<Int> = MutableStateFlow(0)
        val eventNumber: StateFlow<Int> = _eventNumber
    
    
        @JavascriptInterface
        fun createFirebaseEvent(name: String, params: String) {
            val gson = Gson()
            val mapType = object : TypeToken<Map<String, Any>>() {}.type
            val paramMap: Map<String, Any> = gson.fromJson(params, mapType)
    //        firebaseTracker.trackEvent(name, paramMap)
    
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                _eventNumber.emit(_eventNumber.value + 1)
                Log.i("TAGGED", "createFirebaseEvent: ${eventNumber.value}")
                number = number +1
            }
        }
    }

Here the Composable
@Composable
fun DisplayDialog() {
    val numberEvent by webAppInterface.eventNumber.collectAsState()

//I have tried this way initially 
 LaunchedEffect(numberEvent) {
        Log.i("TAGGED", "Dialog: $numberEvent")
    }
    
 LaunchedEffect(numberEvent) {
        Log.i("TAGGED", "Dialog: $numberEvent")
    }
}


Are you sure webAppInterface is the same instance where createFirebaseEvent is called to increase _eventNumber? Btw., you should use _eventNumber.update { it + 1 } instead of emit, but that shouldn't affect your problem.

Yes , this is correct, is the same one, the thing is that this information is coming from a webview, and what I am trying to do is detect such events and after that pass it to the composable, but is not working, I only see the values the first time, but when I click the button from the web on the @JavascriptInterface the value is assigned, but on the composable is not

Can you provide a [mre]? Something that we can execute to see for ourselves? The code you have so far looks good, the problem is most likely somewhere else.
